# In word 365 where can I find the template variables to place them on the page?

Tags: c#, ms-word

We have an existing legacy system where I'm able to download existing templates, update them and save them as documents with my edits.  Here is a portion of the code.

```
#region Open existing Template and write something to it.
    object missing = Type.Missing;
    Word.Application app = new Word.Application();
    Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Open(@"C:\\test395310.dot", ref missing, true);
    doc.Activate();                                                    
    doc.Variables["CASE PLAN_PLAN_STATUS"].Value = "asdf1";
    doc.Variables["CASE PLAN_PROGRAM"].Value = "asdf2";
    doc.Fields.Update();
#endregion
```

Using similar logic I'm attempting to create a new word template with 2 variables.

```
private static void CreateTemplate()
    {
        //have it open word and create a template with fields from gen
        object missing = Type.Missing;
        Word.Application app = new Word.Application();
        Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, true);
        doc.Activate();
        doc.Variables.Add("CASE PLAN_PLAN_STATUS", "XXXXX");
        doc.Variables.Add("ANOTHER ONE", "XXXX");
        doc.Fields.Update();
        doc.SaveAs2(@"C:\\newTemplate.dot");
        doc.Close();
        app.Quit();
    }
```

The document is getting created, however in word I cannot find either variable.   My goal is to open word and placement in the template with formatting.  ie

```
Plan Status: <<CASE PLAN_PLAN_STATUS>>
```

If I click insert/Explore Quick Parts/field, I can see various options, but my two variables aren't there.  Anyone know where else to look?   Or a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

## Within your template, you can use DocVariable fields.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-docvariable-field-32a81e22-c5c1-4b16-8097-f0de851db67c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US
It would look like { DocVariable Case_Plan_Plan_Status } with field codes revealed.

#### Unlike Document Properties, Document Variables can only be created, modified, or deleted using vba.

There are no built-in Document Variables. There is no tool built into the user interface for seeing what is available among variables.

#### I do know of several good Add-Ins for manipulating them in the user interface.

One is Chris Woodman's old Keyboard Shortcut Organizer.
http://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#ChrisWoodman
This one lets you view, create, edit and delete variables from within Word but does not create a DocVariable field, leaving that for you to do.

Another is Graham Mayor's or Greg Maxey's utility.
http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/cc_var_bm_doc_prop_tools_addin.html
or
http://www.gmayor.com/BookmarkandVariableEditor.htm
Both of these last two can add a DocVariable Field to your document after you select the variable from a list.